# Display just system time android

Tags: android

I am trying to make an alarm app and I need to use the system time in order for it to work. However, that's all I want. the way I am doing it now gets both date and time:

```
//creates timer
t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //gets time ad date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        //time format
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");//<===What I am using
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime()); //<====== What I am using 

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                //sets time every second
                timeasofnow.setText("Current time: "+c.getTime());                      
            }
        });
    }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

EDIT: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had not used the date format yet. Silly me.

Comment: you are defining `formattedDate`, but not using it.

Comment: yes but that is not the problem

Comment: then I don't understand your question.